# Why npm email templates won't load?

Tags: node.js, npm, email-templates

I use the npm library email-temaplates on several NodeJS apis deployed on the same environment with the same configuration.

```
node: v10.16.0
npm: 3.10.10
email-templates: 8.1.0
mailparser: 3.6.2
html-to-text@8.2.1
```

When the library is imported,

```
const Email = require('email-templates');
```

I have the following error on one of my apis:

```
...node_modules/mailparser/node_modules/html-to-text/lib/html-to-text.cjs:1838
2022-12-21 10:52 +01:00:     tableToString: (rows) => tableToString(rows, formatOptions.rowSpacing ?? 0, formatOptions.colSpacing ?? 3),
```

Despite the exact same code is working on the others apis.

The only difference is in the file `package-lock.json`. Oddly, the dependencies with `html-to-text` listed aren't the same even if the package.json are the same.

Here is the package.json file:

```
{
 "dependencies": {
    "async-redis": "^2.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "ejs": "^3.1.5",
    "email-templates": "^8.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-basic-auth": "^1.2.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.2.0",
    "express-validator": "^6.7.0",
    "helmet": "^4.2.0",
    "jwt-simple": "^0.5.6",
    "mime-types": "^2.1.34",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.7.3",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "mysql2": "^2.2.5",
    "node-cron": "^2.0.3",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.16",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "redis": "^3.1.2",
    "socket.io": "2",
    "socketio-jwt": "^4.6.2",
    "swagger-jsdoc": "^6.2.1",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.3.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.1",
    "winston": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6"
  }
}
```

I've tried other versions of the npm library email-templates (10.0.1, 10.0.0, 9.0.0) but each time, its the same result.

I've tried to rollback to a previous version of my API, it's working despite the package configuration (package.json) and the usage of that library is exactly the same than the ones of the newer version of my API. I'm stuck since few days now :/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute

```
npm cache verify
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm install
```

That will clean up and recreate the package-lock.json
Sure you are using everywhere same node version.

Hint. Node 10 is very old
Run

```
npm audit
```

This will analyse the vunerabilities.

If this doesnt help, post your package.json.

UPDATE

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "create a new folder inside execute:",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "async-redis": "^2.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "ejs": "^3.1.5",
    "email-templates": "^6.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-basic-auth": "^1.2.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.2.0",
    "express-validator": "^6.7.0",
    "helmet": "^4.2.0",
    "jwt-simple": "^0.5.6",
    "mime-types": "^2.1.34",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.7.3",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "mysql2": "^2.2.5",
    "node-cron": "^2.0.3",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.16",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "redis": "^3.1.2",
    "socket.io": "2",
    "socketio-jwt": "^4.6.2",
    "swagger-jsdoc": "^6.2.1",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.3.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.1",
    "winston": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6"
  }
}
```

node version 10.13.0

index.js

```
const Email = require('email-templates');
console.log(Email)
```

just to check the error

```
node index
[Function: Email]
```

Comment: Thanks. That doesn't help. I've updated my post with the package.json.

Comment: Thanks. That doesn't help. I've updated my post with the package.json.

Comment: Do one thing. Delete again all. Then revove the entry of that module in the package.json. npm i. Than install the package without version. It should install a version which is related to your other dependencies.

Comment: I've tried. The version then installed has was one that I have already tested. '??' seems to be the issue because it's supposed not to work with node version 10. But I cannot understand why it's working for some apis and not for that specific one.

Comment: @Laurent Got it running with node 10. After some trials. With that version the error is not comming. Posted it in my answer

Comment: You got it ! Using library email-templates@^6.0.1 works and all the email functionalities keep running on my apis. You save my life :)